# Nested Groups in LINQ with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have query below, which groups students result data by `class`, `group`, `enrollment` as shown in code

```
public List<PassingRatioDTO> GetStudentPassingRatio()
{
    using(SMSEntities em=new SMSEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            List<PassingRatioDTO> result = (from results in em.ResultDetails
                    where results.ExamDate.Year == 2016
                    group results by new {results.Class_Id, results.Group_Id, results.EnrollmentId } into groupedRresult
                    select new PassingRatioDTO()
                    {
                        Percentage = (((groupedRresult.Where(s => s.Status == "Pass").Count()) * 100) / groupedRresult.Count()),
                        ClassName = groupedRresult.Where(s => s.Class_Id == s.ClassDetail.Class_Id).Max(s => s.ClassDetail.ClassName),
                        GroupName = groupedRresult.Where(s => s.Group_Id == s.GroupDetail.Group_Id).Max(s => s.GroupDetail.Group_Name),
                        Year = groupedRresult.Max(s => s.ExamDate.Year),
                    }
            ).ToList();

            return result;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
   }
```

I want to group this query result again and count Percentage (which is a derived column) where percentage is greater then 40..

Comment: @AlperTungaArslan how it will count percentage Count(Percentage).

at client side want to know how many students have passed in a class

Comment: So you want the number of PassingRatioDTO objects in your list, where Percentage > 40?

Comment: @grek40 yeah something like this, want to know class "ABC"  have how many students have percentage >40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have your initial query result, you can group it by your grouping criteria (`ClassName`) and count the number of in-group entries, that match your criteria (`Count(x => x.Percentage > 40)`):

```
var results = GetStudentPassingRatio();
var passingCounts = from result in results
    group result by result.ClassName into classResults
    select new /* some object type */
    {
        ClassName = classResults.Key,
        PassCount = classResults.Count(x => x.Percentage > 40)
    };
```